# How to read the text of td in a grid after refreshing a grid using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid in my MVC view for which I'm trying to find the value of a column after refreshing(postback) but I still get the value that is before postback.

```
if( $("#NonPromoJobList1").after(':load')){
 var temp = $('#NonPromoJobList1 tr').find('td[name = "NPCount"]').text();
   var jobtitle = temp.substr(0, 1);
    }
```

how do I get value of a grid column "NPCount" after refreshing the grid?

Comment: How is the view refresh implemented in code?

Comment: is this inside a $(document).ready or $(window).load ?